# How to open file as read-only in IntelliJ Idea, without changing its attributes?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, editor

In IntelliJ IDEA, I am sometimes opening files from outside the project, and want to protect them against my accidental changes.

Is it possible to toggle the editor to read-only mode? They have the [Reader mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reader-mode.html) which activates automatically if the file itself is read-only or when I open a library source code. However I don't know how to force the reader mode for an arbitrary file.

I am ***not asking*** how to change the file attribute to read-only.
I want to **keep the file editable** in the file system, and just have it read-only in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an official answer from JetBrains:

> Unfortunately, it seems there is no possibility for now to enter Reader Mode without making a file itself read-only.

EDIT:

On 04 Mar 2024 JetBrains created a change request [Have a readonly mode without changing file attributes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-348146). Let's see how it is progressing :)